# how to handle multi boolean states in one onClick event in React;

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 6 sidebar drop menu.

when I click the title, it will show sub-menu.

I can handle that with each onClick function.

like

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  one: false,
  two: false,
  three: false,
  four: false,
  five: false,
  six: false,
});

const oneHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setState({ ...state, one: !state.one });
}

const twoHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setState({ ...state, two: !state.two });
}
```

and in return

```
<div onClick={oneHandler}>First</div>
{state.one ? (
  <div>Something</div>
  ):(
   ""
 )}
<div onClick={twoHandler}>Second</div>
{state.two ? (
  <div>Something</div>
  ):(
   ""
 )}

...repeat
```

it works but bad codes I think.

So, I tried to make that using one onClick event.

like

```
const clickHandler = (value) => {
  setState({...state, value: !state.value});
};

...

<div onClick={()=> oneHandler(one)}>First</div>
```

but in console, it just show false.

I just wanna make it clear and shortly

Can you guys recommend any other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const clickHandler = (value) => {
  setState({...state, [value]: !state[value]});
};

...

<div onClick={()=> clickHandler('one')}>First</div>
<div onClick={()=> clickHandler('two')}>First</div>
<div onClick={()=> clickHandler('three')}>First</div>
```

I guess this will solve your issue.

Comment: Please add some explanation as to what changes you are suggesting and how it is helping. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).